# Can't undo comment upvote if page refreshes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, upvotes

I just upvoted a comment and instantly realised that was a mistake. Approximately 5 seconds had passed, so I wasn't beyond the 60s limit. It seems like the addition of another comment by another user locked in my vote.

I confirmed similar behaviour by upvoting a comment, refreshing the page, at which point I couldn't undo the up-vote.

I'm guessing this is a minor bug?

Comment: No, this is very much by design. See [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1170/164403) in the über-meta.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Can you explain where in that page this issue is discussed? Perhaps it's buried in some comments somewhere, although a search for "refresh" finds nothing.

Comment: From [waffles' answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/164403) (emphasis mine): *You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds,* ***provided you did not navigate away***, as well as *We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past.* ***The only use case is undoing a mis-click.***

Comment: I suppose I can't argue with "***The only use case is undoing a mis-click***". I had assumed it was acceptable to reverse a vote (within a short time window) because you realise it was erroneous, but not a mis-click. Ok, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Maybe a passing mod can mark this as [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: If you're going to keep the question around, someone should also post the above comments/information as an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Good idea and done. I think it's worth leaving this question around as it's not completely clear, to me at least, that refreshing the page is enough to lock a vote in.

Comment: This should be changed. It is very irritating. I had some sort of GUI/click issue and did not intend this, but really, it should be an undone policy. Why can't I change my mind (if that is what I wanted to do, and this is not a GUI error). Either way, it is horrible GUI behavior, and poor design.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Frédéric Hamidi [kindly pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269961/cant-undo-comment-upvote-if-page-refreshes?noredirect=1#comment85440_269961) that this issue is addressed within [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment). Quoting from the main answer (emphasis mine):

> You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, **provided you did not navigate away**.... The only use case is undoing a mis-click.

Empirical evidences suggests that refreshing the page or clicking the link to reveal recently posted comments counts as navigating away.

At first this irked me, but I suppose if "the only use case is undoing a mis-click", then there is no need to have done either of those actions. I was wanting to reverse my vote having seen other comments and it seems this isn't a supported use case.