# Unable to remove "useful comment" mark

Tags: discussion

Why are "useful comment" marks locked?

I marked a comment on a question as helpful (and also added a follow up comment to add more details to the original comment).

Then the commenter edited their comment to add an extra statement that wasn't actually correct.

I am now unable to remove the "helpful" mark - why?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Can't undo comment upvote if page refreshes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269961/464709).

Comment: Definitely related, and answers the question - although doesn't help my situation, where it looks like I've said an incorrect statement is useful.  Although I have added another comment which questions it later

Comment: Indeed it may look like someone as supported an incorrect statement (but there's no direct link to you). On the other hand, the commenter can only edit for 5 minutes after posting a comment, and a pencil icon appears next to the comment to indicate it has changed since it was posted (we do that to [protect Barack Obama](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing/34004#34004)).

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind it, but the pencil just says it's edited - it doesn't give any indication what was editing, or when it was edited... or when the useful-mark was made.  I would suggest the majority of people will see the mark, read the comment and ignore the pencil icon

Comment: Never mind, not important enough to worry about (despite my comments above making it look otherwise).  Thanks for your response  :-)